# How to install Ubuntu as a portable SSD drive that can be carried to other computer?

Tags: boot, ssd

From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/276351/910555), I should be able to create a portable SSD drive to use in multiple computers. What I did was install Ubuntu on an external drive and set boot flag on it (on the external drive). After finish, it run on the computer used for installing it. But when I moved it to other computer, it is a dead fish. What did I do wrong?

## Update

#### [18/9/2019 | 20:20]

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64
- The computer used for installation run UEFI
- No multiple partitions, only one handles everything
- On the second computer side:

  - I tried has a Window boot, Ubuntu (hidden boot, only runs by directly access to the drive throught `F11`.
  - Booting to external SSD will cause an error 'missing boot file please insert boot device and press any keys' or something similar on black screen.

#### [28/10/2019 | 17:01]

```
Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sde.
```

Comment: Do these computers have the same hardware?

Comment: boot flag (your question), and bootable (answer you linked) are not exactly the same thing.  On which drive was `grub` installed?   (it would need to be the external drive), and was the bios/uefi on each machine setup to enable booting a plugged in drive (it may require a function key to pull up a menu to boot it).

Comment: Yaron I think it has, same graphic card and same RAMs. @guiverc I'm not sure, I see `/boot/grub` but couldn't track it drive. However, I'm sure about this because I has done the same thing for USB stick and it works well. I don't know why it couldn't work the same for hard-drive.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu, but `grub` is written in two locations; stages 1.5 & up are written in the /boot/grub/ directory on a disk partition, but stage 1 is written to the device you pick at installation (it's the MBR; or first 512 bytes of the device/disk, which contains the pointer to the later stages) - this is the bit that makes grub bootable  (boot flag is ignored by many devices today).  (*I'm skipping UEFI for simplicity*)

Comment: You can install grub to external drive. But its default is to install to internal drive & then you have to copy to external drive. Ubuntu Installer uses wrong bootloader location for USB/sdb UEFI installs 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457
Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
External drives only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi but that file as copy of  shimx64.efi expects /EFI/ubuntu, so both folders needed for a full install on external drive.

Comment: @oldfred I think I have a vague idea about what you were talking about. However, I still not fully get it. How can I find the `/EFI`? I didn't see it in root. Also about mount and unmount what drives? I'm not really good with boot stuffs, do you have a tutorial for dummy. I couldn't understand what people talked in the repo link.

Comment: If an UEFI install it is mounted with fstab at /boot/efi. It is at /EFI/ubuntu. so in your install it is /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu. You normally have to use live installer to have partitions unmounted to edit them. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair See also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295

Comment: You're right, I saw the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` dir. It has 4 exe, 1 config, 1 CSV and 1 empty dir. Also, here is the Boot-info summary report: https://imgur.com/43oCiD2 . BTW, does modifying Linux boot harm Windows boot?